# True & False in a function def

Tags: python

I understand what the function below does, but I don't quite get the significance (or difference) between returning `True` and `False`.

Both clauses make the program exit; i.e. upon entering a positive or negative response, the Python prompt is returned, so what actually changes internally?

Also, if I were to *design* such a function myself, should I use `True` or `False` if I just wanted the program to return the prompt to me without actually doing anything?

```
def ask(prompt, retries = 4, reminder = 'Please try again!'):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt)
        if response in ('y', 'yes'):
            print('Got y or yes!')
            return True
        if response in ('n', 'no', 'nope'):
            print('Got n or no or nope!')
            return False
        retries = retries - 1
        if retries < 0:
            raise ValueError('Invalid user response!')
        print(reminder)

ask('Do you wanna quit?')
```

Comment: It depends from your application, if you need to pass the return of the function somewhere else then it makes a difference otherwise you might as well just use return.

Comment: If you not use the returned value, you may use return only (Without True or False)

Comment: I would say it has different return values in case you want to ask the user something else like: "Do you really want to buy this?" then you could do a `if ask('Do you really want to buy this?')` for example

Comment: Got it, many thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions rarely get used alone. Returning `True` or `False` here is to help the rest of your program determine what to do. For example:

```
if ask('Do you like cheese?'):
    order_cheese() # Some function you've previously defined
```

However, if your function is designed to return to the prompt, you can use [sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) to return a success code that calling *programs* (vs functions) can take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user's answer can be one of two sides `y or n`, `yes or no`, `y or nope`, `yes or nope`, `y or no` in any order, the function simply maps this list of dichotomies into a simple `True` or `False`. So you can use the function as a condition to perform an action.

```
if ask('Are you ill?'):
    print('Go see a physician')
else:
    print('Go hiking')
```

Without having to re-evaluate the user's original verbose response.

This is quite consistent with the idea of ensuring a `function` has only one *function*, which in this case is to *booleanise* a user's response or throw an error if the response is inconsistent after a number of trials